# Can't find which file this is located in.

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, joomla

I have paid for my template and I have what appears to be a div that is showing up in my code. It isn't showing up on my website but when my site is searched it shows up in the code and I don't want it there. This is what it says: `<div style="display: none;"><a title="Joomla Templates" href="http://www.zootemplate.com">Joomla Templates</a> and Joomla Extensions by ZooTemplate.Com</div>`

I have checked the index.php file in both the template folder and the root folder. I have checked the footer module file and disabled it within joomla. I read that someone said something about it being in the template parameters, I guess I don't know where that would be. Can someone please help that knows about Joomla 1.5? Thanks.

Comment: It could possibly be coming from a plugin or a framework for the template. Kind of hard to tell without knowing which template it is. Simply have a look around more or contact the developer of the template

Comment: Searching through all files contents in your Joomla project should be the fastest way. Did you try it?

Comment: Isn't it against the TOS to remove copyright? If no, then ask author

Comment: I can remove it. It is in my agreement. This is an older template that I got from out of country. I can't reach them. It isn't a huge deal but I don't like the fact that my website is linking to their page in the background. It is for a church site so kindof picky about where it links to.

Comment: what do u mean by saying "when my site is searched it shows up in the code" ? do u mean Search engines like google ? and by the code showing you mean the description under the title of your page ! ? pls be specific about your problem :) maybe its jut the Description meta tag !

Comment: Don't forget that search engine results need some time to get updated, the descriptions aren't updated live.

Comment: When I do an SEO search and it shows all of the external links that are coming from my site it shows this. So even though it is not visible on the site it is in the code and getting picked up by the search engines.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome:

1. Right click on the page, left click 'Inspect Element'.
2. Open the 'drawer' (top bar of the inspect element area, 4th from right)
3. On the 'drawer' tabs, where 'Console' is currently selected, click 'Search'
4. Search for this string (or a part of it). It will search the documents/scripts/stylesheets on the page